# compare two persian strings in android

Tags: android, string, utf-8, compare, persian

hi friend

i have two strings in persian language in android for example

String a = "آرمین";
String b = "آرمین2";

how can i compare this strings in android?
are there any method ?

Comment: use `.equals()` like  `a.equals(b)` and it's not related to persian or other language, if you want compare two String in java you need use `.equals()` method

Comment: Interesting.. even Java does not gives Locale for persian.

Comment: my friend i found the problem .
when i get the persian text from edit text for example "سلام" and compare it with a string for example string a = "سلام" equal is return false
so anyone have idea to solve it ?

Comment: @user3578166 I'm iranian too and I always work with persian text, i don't have any problem with .equals method, post your code because i think problem is some where else

Comment: @user3578166 can you iterate over all characters in the string and print their numeric codes for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses length() and charAt(index i) methods to implement String.equals() method.

```
    String string1 = "test";
    String string2 = "2test";
    int test=0;
    if(string1.length() == string2.length()){
        for (int i=0;i<string1.length();i++){
            if(string1.charAt(i)==string2.charAt(i))
                test++;
        }
    }
    if(test == string1.length()){
        System.out.println("Strings are equal");
    }else
        System.out.println("Strings are not equal");
```

Comment: You just reimplemented `String.equals`.

Comment: @user3578166 specified that " equals is not work for persian ", so i implemented that functionality using other methods.

Comment: But since your code does exactly the same thing, it won't work (whatever that means) either.

Answer (score -1):

Example :

```
    String a = "آرمین"; String b = "آرمین 2";
    if(a.equals(b))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Are Equal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not Equal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Good Luck
موفق باشی

Comment: my code is : name1[i].equals(textBox.getText().toString())  name1 is a String [] but this code is always returns false:(

Comment: I just got the test And worked. Maybe you're trying to save project, Not selected "Save as UTF-8"  If this option is chosen , program runs correctly.

Comment: my friend i found the problem .
when i get the persian text from edit text for example "سلام" and compare it with a string for example string a = "سلام" equal is return false
so anyone have idea to solve it ?

Comment: @user3578166 ho said " equals is not work for persian " ?? I'm iranian and i work with that. see your code, problem is some where else, maybe you insert one space in your text